# Omitting bad data in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query:
`SELECT DISTINCT STOCK_NUMBER, COLOR FROM MY_TABLE`

I have tried adding `WHERE COLOR <> '/'` but it removes a non duplicate item from my inventory. I am trying to figure out something like if current stock number matches next stock number compare them and choose the longer string.

Schema:

```
ID: numeric (18,0) NULL,
STOCK_NUMBER varchar (30),
COLOR varchar (30)
```

Sample data:

```
STOCK_NUMBER | COLOR 
---------------------
    B1       | Black/
    B3       | Black/Gray
    B3       | /Gray
    B6       | /White
    B7       | /
    B7       | Black/Red
    B8       | /
```

Current Output:

```
STOCK_NUMBER | COLOR 
---------------------
    B1       | Black/
    B3       | Black/Gray
    B3       | /Gray
    B6       | /White
    B7       | /
    B7       | Black/Red
    B8       | /
```

Desired Output:

```
STOCK_NUMBER | COLOR 
---------------------
    B1       | Black/
    B3       | Black/Gray
    B6       | /White
    B7       | Black/Red
    B8       | /
```

How can I omit the STOCK_NUMBER bad data duplicates to get the desired output?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is the logic for a bad row?

Comment: What if you have `black/grey` and `yellow/red` both have same string length. You need define what is **BAD** data

Comment: This is a great example of why data modelling is important.

Comment: start with SELECT STOCK_NUMBER, MAX(COLOR) FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY STOCK_NUMBER, COLOR

Comment: Your table design violates the basic principle `1NF`. With this design you'll have many complication in getting the desired output. First fix the table design.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That is where my struggle is. I have not seen any cases like that in the data. So I did not put it in the example.

Comment: If you can't define what is a bad data, then you can't do a query to filter and probably will have to do a manual search

Comment: To everyone complaining about the design. I know... its an old table. I cant do anything about it. I wouldn't have to ask if it weren't for the fact that I am trying to find a solution to this problem. I am not looking to redefine the problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My definition of bad data is: if a stock_number has a duplicate, if the color is missing on left, right or both of '/' it should be omitted else it stays in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Go ahead and down vote a real life problem with legacy data. This is a real legitimate question.

Comment: First don't get upset for down vote that can happen for multiple reason. I didn't down vote but as is the question right now can't be solved. But after you answer my question is when the problem make sense. And I think forpas solutions is what you need.

Comment: That was not pointed toward you, but toward the people that do not like thinking outside of the box. Thank you for asking the right questions to help us solve this. I believe that solution will work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sample data you can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from my_table t
where not exists (
  select 1 from my_table
  where stock_number = t.stock_number and color <> t.color and color like '%' + t.color + '%' 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab367fdeb4863d3f44a12bd96d905320).
Results:

```
> STOCK_NUMBER | COLOR     
> :----------- | :---------
> B1           | Black/    
> B3           | Black/Gray
> B6           | /White    
> B7           | Black/Red 
> B8           | /
```

Comment: I think you are removing the long string and not the shortest one.

Comment: Check the demo.

Comment: @forpas I am trying to add another condition for bad data, but it seems to be skipping over. I am adding ```and color is not null``` inside the where not exists clause.

Comment: Add the condition in the main where clause: `where t.color is not null and not exists(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the longest color per `stock_num`.  If so:

```
select stock_num,
       max(color) keep (dense_rank first order by length(color) desc) as color
from t
group by stock_num;
```

You can also do this in various other ways.  Using a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.stock_num = t.stock_num and
                        length (t2.color) > length(t.color)
                 );
```